# Чтение из файла в виде нужного типа

Tags: словари

Был создан текстовый документ. В него красиво записан словарь,это необходимо для промежуточного контроля данных.Это было сделано в одной из небольших промежуточных программ моего проекта.

Походу выполнения кода мне необходимо обращаться к этому словарю.

Проблема такая  -при дальнейшем написании кода мне необходимо обращаться к этому словарю,но при каждом нажатии кнопки Run этот словарь заново создается,что очень замедляет процесс.Так как я записал этот словарь в .txt документ(с сохранением всего синтаксиса словаря) хотелось бы в уже новой промежуточной подпрограмме просто открывать текстовик ,но что бы компьютер видел его именно как словарь,ибо сейчас с помощью метода .read() он видит содержимое словаря как str.

вопрос- как заставить код "увидеть" содержимое словаря в виде нужного типа?

Comment: смотря каким способом вы решаете эту задачу. могу, например, предложить очень простое решение на java. на каком языке пишите свои приложения вы, я понятия не имею. но в общем случае существует такая вещь, как база данных. используйте ее для словаря и ваши проблемы отпадут сами по себе.

Comment: Python 3,если не сложно